# Python identify file with largest number as part of filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have files with a number appended at the end e.g:

```
  file_01.csv
  file_02.csv
  file_03.csv
```

I am looking for a simple way of identifying the file with the largest number appended to it. Is there a moderately simple way of achieving this? ... I was thinking of importing all file names in the folder, extracting the last digits, converting to number, and then looking for max number, however that seems moderately complicated for what I assume is a relatively common task.

Comment: So you want to read all file names from a directory and get the filename having largest number in its name ?

Comment: yes, so in this case, i would want to know that it is "file_03.csv" (the part of the "file_" is consistent every time)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if the filenames are really formatted in such a nice way, then you can simply use `max`:

```
>>> max(['file_01.csv', 'file_02.csv', 'file_03.csv'])
'file_03.csv'
```

but note that:

```
>>> 'file_5.csv' > 'file_23.csv'
True
>>> 'my_file_01' > 'file_123'
True
>>> 'fyle_01' > 'file_42'
True
```

so you might want to add some kind of validation to your function, and/or or use `glob.glob`:

```
>>> max(glob.glob('/tmp/file_??'))
'/tmp/file_03'
```

Comment: What would be the best way to extract the integer 3 from the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x=["file_01.csv","file_02.csv","file_03.csv"]
print max(x,key=lambda x:re.split(r"_|\.",x)[1])
```